# value of string is not changing even after i changed it in my code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I have created a simple react application in which the user can upload post like in instagram. If a user posted a new post, all the users will be notified with a message like 'new post added'. If i changed the value from 'new post' to 'new notification' it still shows 'new post' I don't know why. can someone help to clear it.

> index.js

```
 webpush.sendNotification(pushConfig, JSON.stringify({
        title: 'New Post ',
        content: 'New Post added!',
        openUrl: '/help'
      }))
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        })
    });
```

> sw.js

```
importScripts("/src/js/idb.js");
importScripts("/src/js/utility.js");

var CACHE_STATIC_NAME = "static-v30";
var CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME = "dynamic-v2";
var STATIC_FILES = [
  "/",
  "/index.html",
  "/offline.html",
  "/src/js/app.js",
  "/src/js/feed.js",
  "/src/js/idb.js",
  "/src/js/promise.js",
  "/src/js/fetch.js",
  "/src/js/material.min.js",
  "/src/css/app.css",
  "/src/css/feed.css",
  "/src/images/main-image.jpg",
  "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700",
  "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons",
  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-lite/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css"
];

self.addEventListener("install", function(event) {
  console.log("[Service Worker] Installing Service Worker ...", event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_STATIC_NAME).then(function(cache) {
      console.log("[Service Worker] Precaching App Shell");
      cache.addAll(STATIC_FILES);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener("activate", function(event) {
  console.log("[Service Worker] Activating Service Worker ....", event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(keyList) {
      return Promise.all(
        keyList.map(function(key) {
          if (key !== CACHE_STATIC_NAME && key !== CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME) {
            console.log("[Service Worker] Removing old cache.", key);
            return caches.delete(key);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});

function isInArray(string, array) {
  var cachePath;
  if (string.indexOf(self.origin) === 0) {
    // request targets domain where we serve the page from (i.e. NOT a CDN)
    console.log("matched ", string);
    cachePath = string.substring(self.origin.length); // take the part of the URL AFTER the domain (e.g. after localhost:8080)
  } else {
    cachePath = string; // store the full request (for CDNs)
  }
  return array.indexOf(cachePath) > -1;
}

self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
  var url = "https://pwagram-68415.firebaseio.com/posts";
  if (event.request.url.indexOf(url) > -1) {
    event.respondWith(
      fetch(event.request).then(function(res) {
        var clonedRes = res.clone();
        clearAllData("posts")
          .then(function() {
            return clonedRes.json();
          })
          .then(function(data) {
            for (var key in data) {
              writeData("posts", data[key]);
            }
          });
        return res;
      })
    );
  } else if (isInArray(event.request.url, STATIC_FILES)) {
    event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request));
  } else {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        if (response) {
          return response;
        } else {
          return fetch(event.request)
            .then(function(res) {
              return caches.open(CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME).then(function(cache) {
                // trimCache(CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME, 3);
                cache.put(event.request.url, res.clone());
                return res;
              });
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
              return caches.open(CACHE_STATIC_NAME).then(function(cache) {
                if (event.request.headers.get("accept").includes("text/html")) {
                  return cache.match("/offline.html");
                }
              });
            });
        }
      })
    );
  }
});

self.addEventListener("sync", function(event) {
  console.log("[Service Worker] Background syncing", event);
  if (event.tag === "sync-new-posts") {
    console.log("[Service Worker] Syncing new Posts");
    event.waitUntil(
      readAllData("sync-posts").then(function(data) {
        for (var dt of data) {
          fetch(
            "https://us-central1-pwagram-68415.cloudfunctions.net/storePostData",
            {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Accept: "application/json"
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                id: dt.id,
                title: dt.title,
                location: dt.location,
                image:
                  "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pwagram-68415.appspot.com/o/sf-boat.jpg?alt=media&token=bb1cea7e-45bd-40e5-8bf6-109892f54601"
              })
            }
          )
            .then(function(res) {
              console.log("Sent data", res);
              if (res.ok) {
                res.json().then(function(resData) {
                  deleteItemFromData("sync-posts", resData.id);
                });
              }
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
              console.log("Error while sending data", err);
            });
        }
      })
    );
  }
});
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function(event) {
  var notification = event.notification;
  var action = event.action;

  console.log(notification);

  if (action === "confirm") {
    console.log("Confirm was chosen");
    notification.close();
  } else {
    console.log(action);
    event.waitUntil(
      clients.matchAll().then(function(clis) {
        var client = clis.find(function(c) {
          return c.visibilityState === "visible";
        });

        if (client !== undefined) {
          client.navigate(notification.data.url);
          client.focus();
        } else {
          clients.openWindow(notification.data.url);
        }
        notification.close();
      })
    );
  }
});
self.addEventListener("notificationclose", function(event) {
  console.log("Notification was closed", event);
});

self.addEventListener("push", function(event) {
  console.log("Push Notification received", event);

  var data = {
    title: "New!",
    content: "Something new happened!",
    openUrl: "/"
  };

  if (event.data) {
    data = JSON.parse(event.data.text());
  }

  var options = {
    body: data.content,
    icon: "/src/images/icons/app-icon-96x96.png",
    badge: "/src/images/icons/app-icon-96x96.png",
    data: {
      url: data.openUrl
    }
  };

  event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(data.title, options));
});
```

Comment: Shift + F5 in your browser maybe? Wild guess ...

Comment: maybe show us your service worker conifguration idk

Comment: @NumLock Unfortunately its not working :(

Comment: @Ifaruki added :)

Comment: @cbra only the title is wrong or the whole message?

Comment: @Ifaruki need to change both of them

Comment: @Ifaruki any idea?

Comment: @cbra clean cache / unregister sw

Comment: @Ifaruki done :) but still not working